# Customizing the pyro cms ->css and js not working

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url, pyrocms, pyrocms-lex

I want to customize the theme 
In the addons->themes->myprojectname  i kept css,img,js,views,theme.php and i activated the theme from the control panel of the pyrocms

1) In the views->partials->meta.html i have kept the like this

```
{{ theme:favicon file="favicon.ico" }}

{{ theme:css file="style.css" }}

{{ theme:css file="cake-debug.css" }}

{{ theme:css file="global.css" }}

{{ theme:css file="jquery-ui.css" }}
```

My pages i.e, views are in modules but this css is not applying to my page but page.

!)This page is not a pyro cms theme  page ,it is .html page renamed to .php and placed in the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be having css images and js files in seperate folders. Try it like this

```
{{ theme:favicon file="img/favicon.ico" }}

{{ theme:css file="css/style.css" }}

{{ theme:css file="css/cake-debug.css" }}

{{ theme:css file="css/global.css" }}

{{ theme:css file="css/jquery-ui.css" }}
```